# PHP Signature Image Generator

Tags: php, generator, imaging

Basically all I am trying to do is include an image over the background of the signature although every time I try something I get an error saying:

**Resource ID 4**

I would be really thankful for any help I receive on this..

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: image/png"); 

$image = imagecreatefrompng("../imgs/bisig1.png");
$other = imagecreatefrompng("../imgs/avatar.png");
//imagecolorallocate($image, R, G, B) in HEX values
$font_black = imagecolorallocate($image, 2, 1, 8);
$font_blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 25, 0, 255);

$List = "name.txt";
$string = "Account Name";
$string2 = "<img src='$other'>";
//($image, fontsize, rightindent, downindent, data, txtcolour)
imagestring($image, 3, 12, 3, "T17", $font_blue);
imagestring($image, 1, 86, 6, "SOTW", $font_black);
imagestring($image, 1, 110, 6, $string, $font_black);  
imagestring($image, 4, 110, 50, $other, $font_blue); 

imagepng($image); 
imagedestroy($image); 
imagepng($other); 
imagedestroy($other); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

GD isn't HTML (`$string2 = "<img src='$other'>";`) and it won't work
BTW you problably do not get any "Resource ID 4" error as your mime type is png.